# Axes takes up entire screen in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, resize, axes

There must be a simple answer to this. I cannot really find a suitable response after a lot of searching.

This is what I want to make using the GUIDE tool.

[image]

This is what I get. (Note: the plot is made using the subplot function)

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the plot simply fit into the predefined 'axes1' rectangle from the GUIDE interface?

Comment: no, the function `subplot` will override any `axes` already defined in a figure. If you want to plot things on two `axes`, define 2 of them in your guide, then populate them one by one with `plot(x,y,'Parent','your_axe_handle')`

Comment: Hoki it appears this is true. For somereason it does in fact overide the axes. Thank you.

Comment: You should post this as an answer since it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `subplot` function within the GUI it will override the axes defined using `GUIDE`. Instead it is best to plot two separate axes.

```
%this will plot axes 1    
axes(handles.axes1)
plot(x,y)
title('Title of Axes 1'
ylabel('y Label of Axes 1')
xlabel('x Label of Axes 1')

%this will plot axes 2
axes(handles.axes2)
plot(x,y)
title('Title of Axes 2'
ylabel('y Label of Axes 2')
xlabel('x Label of Axes 2')
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this is by putting the axes in a separate panel, thus restraining them to the size of the panel. Hope it helps!

PS: I am using `subplot` too.